# Full screen opaque pop up

Tags: jquery, css

I have this jfiddle. I'm trying to open a popup that is full screen, responsive and on page load. I have it set to popup with a button. The problem is that it's not opening on page load and it's not full screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/rodmbo0m/

Here's my jquery

```
$(window).load(function(){
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$('[data-popup-target]').click(function () {
    $('html').addClass('overlay');
    var activePopup = $(this).attr('data-popup-target');
    $(activePopup).addClass('visible');

});

$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27 && $('html').hasClass('overlay')) {
        clearPopup();
    }
});

$('.popup-exit').click(function () {
    clearPopup();

});

$('.popup-overlay').click(function () {
    clearPopup();
});

function clearPopup() {
    $('.popup.visible').addClass('transitioning').removeClass('visible');
    $('html').removeClass('overlay');

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.popup').removeClass('transitioning');
    }, 200);
}

});
});
```

Comment: my jfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/rodmbo0m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rodmbo0m/1/

This update makes a fullscreen popup.

Just switched positioning to be fixed and set boundaries for all four corners to 0 on popup-body

```
position:fixed;
top:0;
right:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
```

Comment: How do i get it to load automatically on page load.

Comment: Just add:     $('[data-popup-target]').click();
 to your script

Comment: hmm.  $('[data-popup-target]').click();  is not opening it on page load.

Comment: yes that works! Clicking on the background closes the window. How can i create a link to have it close manually on clicking the link

Comment: Also just realized that when you remove the button it stops opening the div on page load. Is there anyway around that. I'd like to just remove the button and have it open on load and have a manual link to close it

Comment: Is there a way to do it without buttons but hyperlinks?

Comment: I just realized you can do it with onClick also. But is there anyway to use a link to open it as well instead of a button?

Comment: I just removed the button from displaying using display:none; Thank you so much!!

Comment: You can thank me by hitting the up vote button next to my answer :)

Comment: oh yes! of course. I thought it was someone else who answered and i was looking for a way to upvote the comments. lol. absolutely!